# how to store data in Ext.Store after recieving httpResponse

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Hi im writing this android app using sencha touch. How do i store data in Ext.Store after recieving an httpRequest response.

```
var result = new XMLHttpRequest();
result.onreadystatechange = function(){
var respXml = result.responseXML;
//store this result in Ext.store
```

}

```
result.open("POST",Uri,true);
result.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
result.send(restbody);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just use

`var id = result.responseText.split('something');`

Then save into a record

```
var record = Ext.create('model',{id:id... });


store.add(record);
```